# Google Maps Glitch iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google maps api for iOS and am experiencing issues whenever a new marker is selected. I have tried looking at other questions but unfortunately they have not solved the issue. The issue is whenever the user taps on a new marker, the camera will glitch before it navigates to the new marker. I have attached a demo to try and offer a better explanation. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B60HdsK9KYQESFRhaGFMc2NuWVk

Comment: Hi @zach , i am using google-map api but i never saw this issue!! i dont think its because of google API.

Comment: Still just in case, check if you are recreating map or clearing content of map. e.g [_mapView clear]